# Retag the misused [vue.js]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) says:

> Vue.js is an open-source, progressive Javascript framework for building user interfaces that aims to be incrementally adoptable. **Questions specific to version 2 of Vue.js should be tagged [vuejs2]**.

However, [4,851 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2+vue.js) out of 15,454 questions seem to misuse this, and this isn't een the tip of the iceberg, most people just use the wrong tag, even when their question is about VueJS 2

What is the best way of solving this situation?

Notice that there are a few differences between VueJS 1 and VueJS 2, and those differences may affect the way you program. Most people use version 2 these days.

Comment: Retagging a question is an entirely normal edit activity, the contributors to a [tag] routinely take care of it.  To be done on the questions that matter, junk doesn't need it.  Notable is that the selective ability of [vue.js] vs [vuejs2] is zilch, they have the exact same set of experts.  So a synonym would be a very simple way to get rid of the grind.

Comment: If anything, that version guidance should be at the start of the excerpt, much like it is done for vuejs2. For the minority that reads these excerpts that might help them choose the right tag.

Comment: reminds me of constant retagging I and many other still do betweeen [tag:angular] and [tag:angularjs]

Comment: @Pac0 which is a waste of your time. It would be more productive and give you better rewards if you just merge everything and be done with it. That way you don't have to worry about not having the correct tag to use the duperhammer, the amount of users with dupehammer would increase, you could drop those complicated filters, your time would be more focused towards answering questions rather than bothering with editing tags, etc...

Comment: @Braiam I am not sure to understand your comment. I am very very far from being able to dupe hammer anything, and confusion between the terms "angular" and "angularjs" is quite common (even though the tag descriptions are clear). What are you suggesting instead of correcting tags (or approving edits of those tags) when I stumble upon such a mis-tagged question ? EDIT : in the case of angular VS angularjs, the difference is important, they shouldn't be merged. Though the merge makes possibly more sense for vue.js

Comment: @Pac0 when I said "you" I meant the collective "you" that are users experts on any of the tag. You spend too much time "correcting" the tags instead doing something more practical and productive like answering questions or broadening your expertise.