# Let's talk about the problems surrounding vue.js and vuejs2 tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I spend a fair amount of time looking at answers / questions specifically about Vue and the reoccurring trend is that more often then not questions are tagged using Vue 1.x tag which is [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js).Whereas they actually meant to tag these questions as [vuejs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2), as I post this the last three questions have both tags added inside [vuejs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2):

- [Can't retrieve user information from the server by using axios (Get) Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706599/cant-retrieve-user-information-from-the-server-by-using-axios-get-vue-js)
- [Vue Nuxt.js wait for template to render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706351/vue-nuxt-js-wait-for-template-to-render)
- [Editing fields with Vue & Vuex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705147/editing-fields-with-vue-vuex)

In the [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) we have another random [nuxt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxt.js) question tagged with Vue.1x which is the wrong tag:

[Error while Deploying nodejs application with NUXT and Vue on Azure Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706650/error-while-deploying-nodejs-application-with-nuxt-and-vue-on-azure-web-applicat)

This even has 2.0 in the title but still has only [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js):

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined VUE 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706429/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-push-of-undefined-vue-2-0)

I could go on to post more but if you've answered questions in this tag more often then not one of the first actions you'll do when answering a question is to re-tag it with the correct tag or remove incorrect tagging. Another issue is when people post either 1.x or 2.x answers to either tag and or have to instantly clarify which version there actually using on occasion if the code snippets are not obvious.

I suppose I just wanted to highlight this and maybe open a conversation about how we might be able to change it so people are less likely to tag there questions incorrectly and to avoid providing incorrect answers.

One way I've thought of solving this could be by changing the tags to be more explicit like for example [vuejs1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs1) and [vuejs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2) where the targeted framework has to be appended to the tag name.

[vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) has 14.9k watchers and 20k questions and [vuejs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2) has 4.1k watchers and 9.1k questions.

The current guidelines for each tag are that all questions specifically targeted towards vue 1.x are tagged with [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) and specifically vue 2.x questions are tagged as [vuejs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2). The wordage for both tags makes it sound like they are not supposed to co-exist whatsoever.

Related is this merge [Merge tags: [vuejs] [vue.js] [vuejs2] [vue2]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335929/merge-tags-vuejs-vue-js-vuejs2-vue2?rq=1) which left us with these two tags.

Related as it details the same symptoms I'm exsplaining here [Retag the misused [vue.js]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365274/retag-the-misused-vue-js?rq=1)

Comment: Well I was thinking that maybe we could actually make the tags more explicit like for instance we could have `vuejs1` and `vuejs2`

Comment: Low-rep users, JavaScript tech, and mistagging. Looks like business as usual.

Comment: @pnuts I updated my question to also include my suggestion, I'm actually happy to help out re-tagging and doing something about it, but I just wanted to seek some advice and see if we can do something constructive.

Comment: I think that potentially just that small change might actually be enough to get users to engage and choose the right tag, it kind of seems like both of these tags are growing at simmilar rates (not sure) and I think a lot of this is due to double tagging.

Comment: It's probably also a good time to think about the tagging situation after they added TS support alongside class components and various other things, with a growing ecosystem it would be nice to get the growing amount of questions tagged correctly so future answers can be certain it's framework x.

Comment: 1.x questions from my experience are a dying breed, it might be good to just have one [vuejs] like you said and having a vuejs1 tag which is targeted towards that framework support as that seems to be how people are already using it.

Comment: To clarify it seems like most people will tag vue.js for 2.x -> current and as they type that one notice vue2js and will then add it, sometimes they just wont at all which renders the question looking like a 1.x. People will post an answer and then it'll get downvoted as people were exspecting 1.x answer, then op will comment saying 'opps I'm acutally using 2.x'

Comment: a good example is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633140/how-to-get-the-component-that-rendered-a-dom-element-with-vue-js#comment90264024_51633140 where I commented initially on that edited answer just to find out it's not a 1.x question.

Comment: Definitely clarity for the answer's is something I think people would appreciate.

Comment: I'm happy to gather more questions other than the ones I quickly grabbed from the front of the queue to add to the OP, though I'll need to do that when I get home. I'm not exactly sure how I can gather the other pieces as I don't have access to stats and I've never used stack exchange explorer.

Comment: Sounds like a good shout, I'll ask in there later today and see if anyone wants to organize a group to re-tag everything, though vue isn't very popular in there from memory.

Comment: Also looks like there's more work to be done as the recent docs changes has killed a bunch of the links in the highest voted questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623833/how-to-remove-hashbang-from-url so far the top two both have broken links to docs in op also

Comment: I added the stats you mentioned into the op, I just wanted to clarify with usage guides am I proposing how I would intend the questions be retagged or how the tag could be changed?

Comment: So say for instance If I was going to start doing a, wouldn't there need to be some kind of yes do it from a mod or some kind of organization to it? I can't imagine I can just start re tagging 20k questions while also dividing them without some kind of permission?

Comment: Furthermore is there a good way I can keep track of where I was at other than just using the above query and keeping a note of which page I'm currently on?

Comment: Alright screw it, it's on this evening I guess it's time to just put some work in and hope I can get others involved.