# Is there a standard we can point to for versioning tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

I came here to point out that the Vue.js tags seem to need some maintenance related to the versions. Then I came across [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335929/merge-tags-vuejs-vue-js-vuejs2-vue2) that didn't receive an answer and [this very detailed discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372074/lets-talk-about-the-problems-surrounding-vue-js-and-vuejs2-tags) that still didn't result in any actions taken to fix it.

I also know that Angular/AngularJS had a lot of similar discussion when the 1.x (AngularJS) to 2+ (Angular) tags were discussed, and I'm sure that spending 5-10 minutes scanning tags we could identify other ones with version issues.

Is there a set policy, rule, or guidance on how to handle versions across all tags?

I have searched the Help pages dealing with tags and the closest guidance is from the Create Tags Privilege page:

> **When should I create new tags?** Most common tags already exist on a
> mature site. You should always favor existing tags; only create new
> tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question does
> cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this
> site.

The recent Angular shift from 1 to 2 (then to 6) shows why just one rule won't work, but that shouldn't stop us from setting guidelines on how/why/where a new software version needs a new tag, how that tag should be formed, and what should happen to tags for older versions.

Is it time to add specific instructions to the help pages for Creating Tags and Creating Tag Synonyms about versions?

Comment: I highly doubt there can be one standard for all tags. Different things are versioned differently. Some rely so heavily on multiple independent implementations (such as web platform technologies) that versioning is practically useless (the [css3] tag is arguably meaningless in 2018).

Comment: That's why I said "policy, rule, or guidance".

Comment: Maybe blunt: Don't create versioning tags until you can no longer find the specific questions you want to answer

Comment: AngularJS/Angular is like python2 and 3, it's a rework and as such pretty much every question is necessary specific to the version.

Comment: Yes, but how does that address guidance for versioning tags?